# Apache Reverse Proxy Using a Network Proxy Credential?

Tags: apache, networking, proxy, gateway

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy on Apache 2.2 (Windows).  I am able to do it on a non-corporate network without any problems.  I am attempting to reverse proxy content from a vendor domain, but keep it under my own domain for SEO reasons.

dev.example.com/stuff ===> devstuff.vendor.com

However, when I try to incorporate this on my internal network, the Internet Gateway proxy is blocking the request, presumably as I'm not properly authenticating the call to the external domain.

dev.example.com ===> Internet Proxy =X=> devstuff.vendor.com

I've been googling every term I can think of and reading the Apache docs and can't find anything which seems to work.  I have tried running Apache as a service with a network account which would have access, but naturally, it's probably not trying to use the proxy at all.

Is there any way to tell Apache to send external ProxyPass requests to use a specific proxy server, and perhaps a specific username/password as well?  I'd love to avoid modifying the proxy or firewall too heavily to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never quite did figure out the "with passing credentials" part, but using the **ProxyRemote** directive, we could pass everything for our devstuff.vendor.com domain through our network proxy.  From there, we had a proxy exception put in to allow from our web server IPs without authentication, since this was an approved arrangement anyhow.

Though, in hindsight, even after solving this, we ended up backing up one step further and just going straight out the firewall for performance reasons (both for the end user with too many hops) as well as negative impacts to our proxy server.